# ADO.NET and SQLBULKCOPY - Max records limit to insert?

Tags: .net, sql, ado.net

Is there a limit to the amount of records that ADO.net can insert in a database at a time? We want to work with a `sqlbulkcopy` but developers are telling us that ADO doesn't insert more than 1000 records at a time, so `sqlbulkcopy` inserting batches of 10000 records is useless. Is this true? Does `sqlbulkcopy` insert large batches 1000 each time until 10000?

I don't think ADO has a max amount of records but they are developers so I am not sure.

Comment: Who would assume that a bulk insert API is maxed out at 1k rows?!

Comment: You should test what's best BatchSize for you. I don't remember exactly but when I had to import 60-180k records into db I had to balance speed and processor load of my web server. Find the right BatchSize that will give you best performance to CPU load ratio.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not true.** In fact, you have to **set** the [`BatchSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize.aspx) property if you want one because the default is `0`, or no limit.

Further, after reviewing the `WriteToServerInternal` method of the `SqlBulkCopy` class, that is the only thing that would limit the number of rows sent in a single batch.

Finally, even if you sent them in **batches** of 1,000 rows, there is no limit to the overall number of rows that can be inserted. Well, except memory of the running machine if it's done via a `DataTable` for example. But if that data is copied from one server to the next via a `SqlDataReader`, there is **no overall limit** that could be reached in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

```
BULKCOPY.BATCHSIZE=1000;
```

It will help you to resolve Bulk Copy Error.